How to disable the Slack can't find someone invite message?
Does anyone know how to get rid of this message?
It is pretty annoying to get Slack ads in the Slack desktop app, while using it as an already paying customer.


You could try using uBlock Origin to hide it.

would that work in the slack app? I don't think so.

[webapps.se] is only for Web Apps. Desktop apps are on-topic on [su], Android apps on [android.se], and iPhone and other Apple products on [apple.se]. If you edit your question to indicate the specific application you are using I can migrate your question to the appropriate site.

That's a bit ambiguous seeing as the slack app is actually a web app under the hood, it's just wrapped in something like Electron or what have you.

But sure I can update, thanks for migrating the question

"the slack app is actually a web app under the hood," Our site's on-topic page defines a web app as "a website which behaves like an application". Wikipedia as "application software that is accessed using a web browser"  For platform-dependent apps, SE has platform-specific sites.
